# Package not found and generated classes are not recognized

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, wsdl2java, cannot-find-symbol

I am using wsdl2java plugin for genreating wsdl in a gradle project.  I am using intellij.

Now the functionality of JAXB seems fine and from some XSD schema several Java classes are generated in build/ folder.
The problem is Intellijg cannot resolve those classes in main project it gives me the error package not found.
I even manually import those package name but still the class names are not resolvable.
Is there anything I am missing?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlJkH.png)

Comment: What files produced from plugin ? Is it .java or .class files in build folder? , i remember wsdl produces .java files in build folder , you need to copy paste to src directory manually to further proceed and code.

Comment: I just saw images , package conventions are also weird, you have com.somthing in main but genearted classes have fr.company name.Try to follow proper convention.

Comment: @anavaraslamurep the files produced are .java

Comment: you need to put those files inside src directory from build folder and try to have proper package namings.

Comment: @anavaraslamurep i don't know how to do that, shoud i just mark those file as source root or what ??